# x86 assembly equivalent of const char[]

Tags: assembly, gcc

So I am trying to figure out what the equivalent of `const char abc[] = "hello"` is in x86 assembly.

To try figure it out, I have written this in C:

```
int count(const char* str)
{
  int i = 0;
  for (; str[i] != '\0'; i++);

  return i;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const char abc[]  = "hello";

  return count(abc);
}
```

And then I had `gcc` convert it to x86 assembly for me using this command:
`gcc -m32 -O0 -S main.c`

Which gives me this:

```
.file   "main.c"
    .text
    .globl  count
    .type   count, @function
count:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $16, %esp
    call    __x86.get_pc_thunk.ax
    addl    $_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_, %eax
    movl    $0, -4(%ebp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    addl    $1, -4(%ebp)
.L2:
    movl    -4(%ebp), %edx
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movzbl  (%eax), %eax
    testb   %al, %al
    jne .L3
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   count, .-count
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $16, %esp
    call    __x86.get_pc_thunk.ax
    addl    $_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_, %eax
    movl    $1819043176, -6(%ebp)
    movw    $111, -2(%ebp)
    leal    -6(%ebp), %eax
    pushl   %eax
    call    count
    addl    $4, %esp
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .text.__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax,"axG",@progbits,__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax,comdat
    .globl  __x86.get_pc_thunk.ax
    .hidden __x86.get_pc_thunk.ax
    .type   __x86.get_pc_thunk.ax, @function
__x86.get_pc_thunk.ax:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    (%esp), %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE2:
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 10.2.0-13) 10.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Now, I *really* don't understand where my "hello" text is?
Can anyone help me understand?

Comment: Try `gcc -Wall -fverbose-asm -m32 -O2 -S main.c` then examine `main.s`; also put `main` and `count` in two different C files (so have a `count.c` file containing the C code of `count`, and some `extern int count(const char*);` declaration in your `main.c`)

Comment: It's disguised as `movl $1819043176, -6(%ebp)` and `movw  $111, -2(%ebp)`. `1819043176=0x6C6C6568=lleh` and `111=0x6F=o`. Due to endianness that gives `hello`.

Comment: Make it `static` if you want the compiler to stick it in `.rodata` instead of constructing it on the stack from immediates.

Comment: @Jester Thank you for your answer, now I understand!